# Regular expression for get all inside commas

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have this json file:

```
{
sql: "CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE    ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
'NAME'           TEXT    NOT NULL,
'AGE'            INT     NOT NULL,
'ADDRESS'        CHAR(50),
'SALARY'         REAL",
}
```

And I need get column names and column type in a JSON file with a regular expressions, but I'm a noob in regular expressions.

All the program is in js.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a clearing house for free labour. Mostly, readers will want to see that you have expended some effort, in order that they may also spend some effort on it too. What we do not want is for folks finding that it is easier to outsource their work to volunteers rather than giving it a try themselves.

Comment: There's two problems here - parsing JSON then finding commas. I suspect it is the latter, but please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  sql: `CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE    ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
'NAME'           TEXT    NOT NULL,
'AGE'            INT     NOT NULL,
'ADDRESS'        CHAR(50),
'SALARY'         REAL`,
};
const regex = /'(.*)'\s*(\S*)/g;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(obj.sql)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```